# How to make window to appear on center screen when restore down button is clicked? - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am developing a small windows application in WPF

My application main window state is set to maximized.

When a user clicks on restore down button, window is loading at random location.
How do I make window to load at center screen on clicking restore down button?

[EDIT] [SOLVED]

```
 private void Window_StateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Normal)
        {
            double screenWidth = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
            double screenHeight = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
            double windowWidth = this.Width;
            double windowHeight = this.Height;
            this.Left = (screenWidth / 2) - (windowWidth / 2);
            this.Top = (screenHeight / 2) - (windowHeight / 2);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You *should* not do that. Use can drag and resize a window  and you should respect that by restoring window to its former location.**

You *can* do that in this way.

Register a handler to [Window.StateChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.statechanged(v=vs.110).aspx), and set the window location in that handler if the current state is Normal.

```
void Window1_StateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Normal)
       //set window location center to screen
}
```